# How to Use Ajax Contolls in ASP.NET application with out installing AJAX Tool Kit on Server

Tags: ajax

I have a ASP.NET Application(.NET4.0) which have multiple Ajax controls like calender extender,Ajax HTML editor etc.While hosting the application on Win server 2008 R2, the web admin don't allow me to install Ajax toolkit on the server.Is there any way to get Ajax controls running with out installing the Ajax tool kit..?

Comment: I made my application refer the Ajax dll copied in the Bin folder of application and deployed it.But it too doesn't works.

Comment: I think the the CSS and the Images for the Ajax is not getting loaded.The WebResource.axd file is not available when i checked using FireBug.Anybody have any idea how to get this axd file.?